# Lein fails to add jars to uberjar

Tags: java, jar, clojure, leiningen, uberjar

I am building a simple web app, which is dependent on a couple of pre-compiled jars and which I want to deploy on Heroku. I put the jars into a `resources` folder and added the following lines to my `project.clj`:

```
:resource-paths ["resources/jsesh-6.5.5.jar"
                 "resources/jseshGlyphs-6.5.5.jar"
                 "resources/java-cup-11b-runtime.jar"
                 "resources/java-cup-11b.jar"
                 "resources/qenherkhopeshefUtils-6.5.5.jar"]
```

Now I am able to run the project using `lein run -m hieroglyphs.web`; however, when I compile everything with `lein uberjar` and try

```
java -cp ./target/hieroglyphs-standalone.jar clojure.main -m hieroglyphs.web
```

The program starts up, but then crashes with a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when it tries to access one of the classes defined in those jars:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jsesh/mdcDisplayer/preferences/DrawingSpecification
```

Should I do something extra so that classes defined in the jars are accessible after compilation?

All the code can be found here: https://github.com/macleginn/jsesh-web

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just having a resources directory doesn't help. You're going to need a proper local Maven repository. Luckily, making one isn't that hard.

Steps:

1. [Install Maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) if needed
2. Make a `lib` folder in your source repository
3. Add `:repositories {"local" "file:lib"}` to your `project.clj`
4. For each of your dependencies run something like `mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=resources/jsesh-6.5.5.jar -DartifactId=jsesh -Dversion=6.5.5 -DgroupId=jsesh -Dpackaging=jar -Durl=file:lib` (that works for the jsesh jar). Note in particular the `artifactId`, `groupId` and `version`
5. Add an appropriate `:dependencies` item for each jar. e.g. for the one I did in Step 4, `[jsesh/jsesh "6.5.5"]`
6. Repeat steps 4 and 5 for each dependency

You'll need to commit the `lib` folder to source control, but can now delete the `resources` folder and the `:resource-paths` bit from `project.clj`

(Heavily based on notes from https://gist.github.com/stuartsierra/3062743)

Comment: Actually, it turns out you can do this without Maven. Replace the `:respositories` bit with `:repositories {"local" {:url "file:lib" :username "" :password ""}}` and run `lein deploy local jshesh 6.5.5 resources/jsesh-6.5.5.jar` (change as appropriate) for the step 4

Comment: You don't need maven or the local maven repo for this.  Just use `:resource-paths` correctly and then run using `java -jar xyz-standalone.jar`

Answer (score 2):

You should change your `java` invocation to use the `-jar` option like so:

```
~/expr/rundir > java -jar ./calc-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar 
main - enter
  (ac/add2 3 5) => 8
main - leave
```

for code that looks like this:

```
calc
├── project.clj
├── resources
│   └── adder.jar
└── src
    ├── calc
    │   └── core.clj

~/expr/calc > cat src/calc/core.clj 
(ns calc.core
  "Contains the core functions for namespace `calc.core`."
  (:require [adder.core :as ac] )
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main []
  (println "main - enter")
  (println (ac/add2 3 5))
  (println "main - leave"))
```

The file `adder.jar` was created using `lein jar` from another project with a single function:

```
(ns adder.core)
(defn add2 [x y]
  (+ x y))
```

The resulting file was renamed "adder.jar" and plopped into the `resources` dir of the `calc` project.  Looking at `project.clj`:

```
(defproject calc  "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description    "FIXME: write description"
  :url            "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url  "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [
    [org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]
    [org.clojure/test.check "0.9.0"]
    [prismatic/schema "1.1.7"]
    [tupelo "0.9.71"]
  ]
  :profiles {:dev {:dependencies []
                   :plugins [
                     [com.jakemccrary/lein-test-refresh "0.22.0"] ] }
             :uberjar {:aot :all}}
  :global-vars {*warn-on-reflection* false}
  :main ^:skip-aot calc.core

  :source-paths       ["src"]
  :test-paths         ["src"]
  :resource-paths     ["resources/adder.jar"]
  :target-path        "target/%s"
  :jvm-opts           ["-Xms500m" "-Xmx2g"]
)
```

The trick is in the line for `:resource-paths`, like so:

```
:resource-paths     [ "resources/adder.jar" ]
```

You need to list each `*.jar` file separately ***as a string*** in the vector. Note that the following ***will not work***:

```
:resource-paths     [ "resources" ]            ; does not find *.jar files
:resource-paths     [ "resources/*.jar" ]      ; wildcards do not work
:resource-paths     [  resources/adder.jar ]   ; without quotes fails
```

We can then create a uberjar for the `calc` project, which will include the stuff from `adder.jar`:

```
~/expr/calc > lein uberjar
Compiling _bootstrap
Compiling calc.core
Compiling tst.calc.core
Created /home/alan/expr/calc/target/uberjar/calc-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Created /home/alan/expr/calc/target/uberjar/calc-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

You want to use the `*-standalone.jar` version for your uberjar.  We copy it to an empty dir to verify it works:

```
~/expr/calc > mkdir -p ../rundir
~/expr/calc > cp target/uberjar/calc-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar ../rundir

~/expr/calc > cd ../rundir
~/expr/rundir > ls -al
total 11744
drwxrwxr-x 2 alan alan     4096 Jan 14 19:22 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 alan alan     4096 Jan 14 19:22 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan 12016027 Jan 14 19:30 calc-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar

~/expr/rundir > java -jar calc-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar 
main - enter
  (ac/add2 3 5) => 8
main - leave
```